# Why `GROUP BY` in hook_views_query_alter() doesn't work?

Tags: 7, database, views

I'm using Views 7.x-3.6 and I tried altering the `GROUP BY` clause with [`hook_views_query_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7) as below:

```
function mymodule_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
    if ($view->name == "view_name"){
      $query->add_groupby('field_name');
      dpm($query);    
    }
}
```

When I look in `$query`, **the `groupby` clause is correctly enabled** but **the SQL query is not affected**: the `GROUP BY` clause doesn't appear:

[image]

What I eventually did is using a Drupal core hook ([`hook_query_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/7)) and it worked fine: the SQL is now affected.

```
function mymodule_query_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  $view_name = 'view_name';
  if ($query->hasTag('views_' . $view_name)) {    
    $query->groupBy('field_name');
  }
}
```

Any reason why my [`hook_views_query_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7) doesn't work? I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do it and.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `add_field()` with `array('function' => 'groupby')` parameter.

```
$query->add_field('node', 'nid', 'node_nid', array('function' => 'groupby'));
$query->add_groupby('node.nid');
```

**Aditional information:**

After using `add_groupby` you might see the next code after `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY node.nid, nid
```

See the next issue: https://drupal.org/node/1578808

To avoid unnecessary GROUP BY conditions add:

```
$query->distinct = TRUE;
```

Comment: How can we remove un-necessary group by without adding $query->distinct = TRUE;

Comment: I spent few hours debugging views group by. But currently I don't know other solution.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. hmm.. i am asking because, if we add $query->distinct = TRUE; then it will add `nid` with group by. It is not necessary for me. Any other option? Do you know how to add unique in views query?

Comment: It was `views_handler_filter::query()` afair. Try `$query->distinct();` in `hook_query_alter`

Answer (score 1):

If you look are the documentation of [hook_views_query_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7), I believe the query is already prepared to run. Eg, replacements have been made by the database API and its about to be sent over the wire to MySQL. Another [example of hook_views_query_alter usage can be seen the BTMash blog](http://btmash.com/article/2011-06-09/correcting-views-queries-using-views-query-alter).

This being the case you no longer have a DB Query Object but the pieces of the SQL statement with expressions, variables, etc as an Array.

I dont have a query in front of me but something like the following untested code is what you want:

```
$query->groupby[0]['field'] = 'field_name';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried but it doesn't work either: again, the `$query` object is altered (differently than the above of course) but again, the SQL query doesn't change!

Comment: did you try a different views hook? _pre_render, or _pre_build? .... I would try hook_views_pre_execute() ...http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_execute/7

Answer (score 1):

This is the way it is done in views_query_alter; the node_access part is not necessary.

```
function xdas_target_audience_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  $controlled_views = variable_get('xdas_target_audience_views', array(
    'landing_products',
    'promotions',
    'landing_coupons',
    'landing_coupons_belvita',
    'landing_coupons_lulu',
    'related_coupon',
    'cuponazo',
    'banner',
    'brands',
  ));
  if (in_array($view->name, $controlled_views) && $view->base_table == 'node') {
    //add node_access to views so we can control access.
    $query->add_tag('node_access');
    $join = new views_join();
    $join->construct('xdas_target_audience_boost', 'node', 'nid', 'nid');        
    $query->add_relationship('xdas_target_audience_boost', $join, 'node');
    $query->add_field('xdas_target_audience_boost', 'score', 'score' , array('function' => 'max'));
    $query->add_orderby(NULL, NULL, 'DESC', 'score');   
    $query->add_groupby('nid');    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but this might help someone else.

In my case I was providing a list of users (using additional module Profile2) with a Taxonomy Term field (https://drupal.org/node/1808320). I was seeing multiple results I could not get rid of through the Views 3 API.

In my custom module I added:

```
/**
    Implementation of hook_views_query_alter()
**/
function MYMODULE_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {

  if($view->name == "provider_results_list" && $view->current_display == "page_1") {

    $query->distinct = TRUE;

    // User the provider uid to make the results distinct: using a taxonomy field for
    // keyword searches brings up multiple results. 
    $query->add_field('profile', 'uid', 'provider_uid', array('function' => 'groupby'));

  }
}
```

The parameters for add_field are

```
add_field(TABLE_NAME, FIELD, FIELD_ALIAS, array('function' => 'groupby'))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are still facing with unnecessary GROUP BY statements added to query, you could remove them in `hook_query_alter()`. I solved the issue with ordering comments by most commented parent comments for example.

So in `hook_views_query_alter()` I have:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function MODULENAME_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'reviews' && $query->orderby[0]['field'] == 'comment_thread') {
    $join = new views_join;
    $join->construct('comment', 'comment', 'cid', 'pid', NULL, 'LEFT');
    $query->add_relationship('c1', $join, 'comment');
    $query->add_field('comment', 'pid', 'c1_pid', array('function' => 'groupby'));
    $query->add_groupby('c1.pid');
    $query->add_orderby(NULL, 'COUNT(c1.cid)', 'DESC', 'comments_count');
    $query->distinct = TRUE;
    $query->orderby[0] = $query->orderby[count($query->orderby) - 1];
    unset($query->orderby[count($query->orderby) - 1]);
  }
}
```

I got error related to inability to group by

> comments_count

field that is actually a result of SQL `COUNT()` function.

I ended up with this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_query_alter().
 */
function MODULENAME_query_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  if (isset($query->alterMetaData['view']->name) && $query->alterMetaData['view']->name == 'reviews') {
    $fields =& $query->getGroupBy();
    foreach (array_keys($fields) as $key) {
      // Remove group by statements from generated query which were actually not set in view query.
      if (!in_array($key, $query->alterMetaData['view']->query->groupby)) {
        unset($fields[$key]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wondered that no one provided a real solution that just works.
There is one such method that I've found [here](http://tylerfrankenstein.com/comment/360#comment-360), many thanks to @b-ravanbakhsh:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_query_alter().
 */
function MODULENAME_query_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  if (isset($query->alterMetaData['view'])) {
    if($query->alterMetaData['view']->name == 'YOUR_VIEW_NAME'){
      // also you can unset other group by critera by using, unset($query->getGroupBy());
      $query->groupBy('users.uid');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 8 and thanks to graceman9 approach, it will be :

```
use Drupal\Core\Database\Query\AlterableInterface;

function MYMODULE_query_alter(AlterableInterface $query) {
  if (isset($query->alterMetaData['view'])) {
    if($query->alterMetaData['view']->id() == 'replace_by_view_machine_name') {
      // Group by UID to remove duplicates from View results
      $query->groupBy('users_field_data.uid');
      // If multilingual site, you should add the following
      // $query->groupBy('users_field_data.langcode');
    }
  }
}
```